# Manga where the female protagonist has amnesia

Tags: otome-x-ranbu

I came across this manga by accident and I can't remember what it was called.

The main character is a teenage girl, who lost her memories from when she was young. I'm not sure but I think her last name was Mochizuki, though it might have been one of her friends who had that name.

- I think she has a male friend who carries a sword with him.
- She makes friends with a blonde girl in her class who kisses her in class, apparently thinking that it might bring back some of the black haired girl's memories.
- The blonde girl has a twin brother who also kissed the black haired girl for the same reason, hoping that she will regain some of her memories.

I know it's not very detailed but anything you can think of that matches this description would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is called [Otome x Ranbu](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=61836)

[image: Otome x Ranbu Cover]

> She is your stereotypical airhead school girl, with one exception, she
>   has amnesia. She recently transferred into a new school where things
>   work different, mainly magic. She is Mochiduki Tsubomi, and she
>   doesn’t remember anything before she transferred. Enter yet another
>   transfer student – the beautiful yet arrogant bishojo, Izayoi Yukiji.
>   She’s after Tsubomi, but why? What does Yukiji want? What mystery does
>   Tsubomi hold?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this exact story as well.Well some of what you said was like the one I was looking for.  It's called Tail of the moon. Check it out.

Comment: Your answer need more detail, [add citations, image, or description.](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/1001/2869) [see another answer here.](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6231/2869)